# Problema com cadastro em codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho um site de cursos feito com codeigniter e está ocorrendo um erro, quando me cadastro por um endereço específico, no caso, este http://www.cursosnet.com.br/site/cadastrar/8/0/13732
ao invés dos dados serem incluidos no banco de dados, retorna o seguinte erro, por exemplo:

```
An Error Was Encountered

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'redirect' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`nome`, `estado`, `cidade`, `pais`, `cep`, `endereco`, `numero`, `bairro`, `telefone`, `como_conheceu`, `email`, `senha`, `redirect`, `data_cadastro_usuario`, `valido`, `hashing`) VALUES ('Cadastro de Testes', 'MG', 'Montes Claros', 'Brasil', '39404000', 'EndereÃ§o de teste', '104A', 'Bairro de teste', '3899999999', 'nao sei', 'teste@emailteste.com.br', '123456', 'site/curso_matricular/13732', '2015-03-20', 'Sim', 'puowqxalnce8jsh6e5swfcte244rpl3gmixwb65mb1187kj42m1nkwv2pvpizvb5gfh2apllzjr5n3v23mvwb1iny26qyfrlnc30')
```

Porém apenas quando é cadastrado por este endereço. O que pode estar ocorrendo?

Comment: Verifica se sua tabela tem uma coluna, "redirect" e verifica se está escrita corretamente!

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se você realmente possui a coluna `redirect` na sua tabela de `usuarios`.
Você provavelmente está utilizando um controller diferente para fazer o cadastro quando o usuário está se cadastrando apartir de um curso.

Pelo que percebi você deseja criar uma especie de redirecionamento após a confirmação do cadastro. Se for realmente este o seu desejo tente utilizar uma Session do PHP para armazenar o local de redirecionamento e depois utilizar uma função do `Helper`de `URL's` do próprio Code Igniter como o:

```
 redirect($_SESSION['redirect_curso'], 'refresh');
```

Para maiores informações consulte a documentação neste [link](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) e para entender melhor como efetuar o redirecionamento consulte este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194189/how-to-get-back-to-the-redirecting-page-after-login-codeigniter).

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente seu script PHP está erroneamente adicionando "redirect" como uma coluna do select, e essa coluna não existe na tabela usuarios no banco de dados.

Basta você corrigir essa parte do script que o erro não vai acontecer mais.